# How to merge different resources in single App.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a long coded App.xaml which contains code for a Custom stylable window that I downloaded from the Internet.

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             xmlns:sw="clr-namespace:MyProject.StyleableWindow"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowColor" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackColor" Color="#FFC3C3C3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowForeColor" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowForeHighlightColor" Color="WhiteSmoke"/>
................
................
................
................
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
```

Yesterday, I downloaded a custom Toggle Button Control. In order to make it function, I tried to merge below code in the App.xaml

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SwitchTypeToggleButton.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

But it doesn't work. I keep getting the following error:

> Each dictionary must have an associated key

My Toggle Button Control Code- (Stored in MyProject > Folder1 > Folder2)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="SwitchTypeToggleButton"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

        <Style.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="Color.Additional.LightGrey">#989EA8</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Color.Additional.MediumGrey">#61656B</Color>
............
............
```

What do I have to do to get rid of the error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resources in app.xaml should look like this:

```
<Application.Resources>    
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="SwitchTypeToggleButton.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowColor" Color="Red"/>
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}"/>
  </ResourceDictionary>      
</Application.Resources>
```

The reason is, that `Application.Resources` actually always needs to be a `ResourceDictionary`. As long as you use "simple" resources, the ResourceDictionary is created implicitly. But as soon as you want to merge another ResourceDictionary you have to specify the containing one explicitly.